# what happens with the variable when appended with apprendChild

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

```
<body>
<h1 class="titulo">Esto es un <b style="visibility: none;">titulo</b> </h1>
<div style="background-color: aliceblue; height: 200px;" class="container"></div>
<div style="background-color: #ccc; height: 200px;" class="container1"></div>
<script>

    

    /************** Create Elements ****************/
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const container1 = document.querySelector(".container1");

    
    const item = document.createElement("LI");

    item.textContent = "this text go inside";
    
    container.appendChild(item);
    container1.appendChild(item);

    console.log(item); 
    
    
    
</script>
```

When appended the variable item to one element, It is not possible to append it again to another element.

As I show in the code, I append the "item" variable to the "container" and then append the same "item" variable to the "container1" and it dissapeared from the "container".

How can I do to maintain the value in the variable to append it to many elements?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, your script should be wrapped in a function via `DOMContentLoaded`, otherwise it won't work reliably (e.g. if you move the `<script>` to your `<head>`).

Comment: What do you mean what happens with the variable ?